# Javascript click href if contains string of numbers

Tags: javascript, href

Want to click an href if it contains a certain substring

```
var styleCode = "827053-010";
document.querySelector("a[href="+styleCode+"]").click();
```

works fine when my variable has letters at the start but doesn't seem to work when im looking for numbers

Comment: A substring selector would be `*=` not `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap attribute value within quotes inside [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var styleCode = "827053-010";
document.querySelector('a[href="'+styleCode+'"]').click();
//                     here ---^-------------^---
```

---

If you are looking for [attribute contains selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) then change it to.

```
var styleCode = "827053-010";
document.querySelector('a[href*="'+styleCode+'"]').click();
//                         ---^---
```

Comment: @JamieSmith : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*=` instead of `=` to include matches anywhere in the property (you also need to quote `styleCode`):

```
var styleCode = "827053-010";
document.querySelector("a[href*='"+styleCode+"']").click();
```

With querySelector, you can use any of the following pattern matching selectors:

`*=` contains

`^=` starts with

`$=` ends with

```js
var styleCode = "827053-010";
console.log(document.querySelector("a[href*='"+styleCode+"']"));
```

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/827053-010/foo">Link with 827053-010</a>
```

Comment: oh yeah sorry missed that out but still wasnt working with *=

Comment: Updated with an example, also forgot to have you quote the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable inside a quotes

```
document.querySelector("a[href='"+styleCode+"']").click();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1sjc81a3/)